# Getting real client IP Address instead of Nginx Container's IP Address on Dockerized Next.js and Nestjs app | X-Forwarded-For

Tags: docker, nginx, next.js, nestjs

I have Next.js 13 (as frontend) and Nestjs (as API) both Dockerized and reverse proxied using `nginx-proxy` image, here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
 api:
    image: gidgud/my:api
    container_name: api
    ports:
      - '6900:6999'
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=api.mywebsite.com
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=6999

  web:
    image: gidgud/my:web
    container_name: web
    expose:
      - '3000'
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    depends_on:
      - api
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=www.mywebsite.com,mywebsite.com
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=3000

  nginx-proxy:
    image: 'nginxproxy/nginx-proxy:latest'
    container_name: 'nginx-proxy'
    volumes:
      - 'html:/usr/share/nginx/html'
      - 'dhparam:/etc/nginx/dhparam'
      - 'vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d'
      - 'certs:/etc/nginx/certs'
      - 'conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d'
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro'
      - './custom_proxy.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/custom_proxy.conf'
    depends_on:
      - web
      - api
    networks:
      - mynetwork
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'

networks:
  mynetwork:
    name: my_network
    external: true
```

My `web` request to `api` using the VM IP Address with the `api`'s exposed port (I'm trying to point it to `api.mywebsite.com` instead, but Next.js giving `TIMEOUT` error when doing server request to it, that's why for now I point it to the VM IP Address).

*Need to know: my `web` is not directly requesting to `api`'s IP Address but it goes through Next.js `rewrites` first. So I 'wrap' the `api`'s IP Address with Next.js `rewrites` feature.*

Okay above is my website setup and here comes the main problem.

**My `api` cannot receive the real client IP Address that comes from `web` request. Instead, it always receives `nginx-proxy` container's IP Address. Moreover, when `web` doing server request to the `api` (Next.js server component), the `api` receives the Docker network default gateway IP Address instead.**

Beside that, I've tried to deploy a different website on Vercel without Docker and try to send request to the `api` (`api.mywebsite.com`) and my `api` can correctly receive the real client IP Address. According to this findings, I suspect the problem is either from the Docker or Next.js setup.

**Question: How do I setup Next.js/Docker so that when it request to `api` it will also send at least the `X-Forwarded-For` header? (for real client IP Address)**

Thank you and for your answers ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After surfing and testing many times, here I come up with this solution.

### Nestjs

In order to receive end user real IP, need to activate `trust proxy` setting like this:

```js
// main.ts
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);
  app.set('trust proxy', ['loopback', 'linklocal', 'uniquelocal']);

  ...
}
```

Got the Reference when trying to rate limit my app: https://docs.nestjs.com/security/rate-limiting#proxies

### Next.js (v13.5.4)

1. Next.js `rewrites` by default doesn't forward end user headers, so I need to append them manually like this:

```js
// middleware.ts
export const config = {
  matcher: '/my-api/:path*',
};

export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  const baseUrl = process.env.API_URL;

  const requestHeaders = new Headers(req.headers);

  const url = req.nextUrl.clone();
  url.protocol = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'https' : 'http';
  url.pathname = url.pathname.replace(/^\/my-api/, '');
  url.href = baseUrl + url.pathname + '?' + url.searchParams;

  return NextResponse.rewrite(url, {
    headers: requestHeaders,
  });
}
```

Other options beside using Next.js `rewrites` would be using `http-proxy-middleware` package to create custom proxy to api.

2. For server request, Next.js `fetch` by default also doesn't forward/include end user headers. So I need to append them in every `fetch` request like this:

```js
import { headers } from "next/headers";

...

const response = await fetch(`${baseUrl}/api${path}`, {
  ...options,
  headers: Object.fromEntries(headers())
});
```

Reference about this server request headers: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/47793

### Nginx

As reverse proxy, to make sure it forwards end user real IP to your web app, need to add these lines in Nginx config:

```bash
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $proxy_x_forwarded_host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $proxy_x_forwarded_proto;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl $proxy_x_forwarded_ssl;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $proxy_x_forwarded_port;
```

In my case, I use `nginx-proxy` docker image that already have above config by default so I don't need to add extra configuration to my Nginx container.

Hopefully this helps! And I still open for other solution, suggestion, and answer, Thanks!